# Convex hull of a quarter of an annulus

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

I just learned about convex hulls and want to confirm I understood it correctly.

> Find the convex hull of $$D= \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : x,y \geq 0, 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4 \}$$

Am I correct that its convex hull is the following?

$$\mbox{conv} (D) = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x,y \geq 0, x + y \geq 1, x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$$

What is the appropriate notation for the set representing the convex hull?

Comment: Isn't $D$ itself already convex, so is its own hull?

Comment: A side remark: the sum of squares, $x^2 + y^2$, is automatically nonnegative, so no need for the $0 \leq x^2 + y^2$.

If the definition of $D$ means intersection of the closed 1st-quadrant and the punctured closed circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $4$, the intersection of two convex sets is itself convex.  Therefore, it is its own convex hull.

As for notation, I've seend [Conv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), $\mbox{co}$, and $\mbox{ch}$.

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. It should be that the sum of squares is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: With your typo corrected: yes, $D_{conv.hull}$ is the convex hull of $D$. As for notation, I would say that whatever notation you choose, you should define it first.

Comment: Thank you, TonyK.